# Can't mount RAID after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 14.04, raid

I just upgraded my box to 14.04 and on bootup I got a message, that my RAID devices can't be mounted automatically so I chose to skip it and work through it after boot time. Now booted up, A mount -a gives me:

```
$ sudo mount -a
[sudo] password for reg: 
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

$
```

while my mdadm.conf looks like:

```
$ cat /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts MAILADDR root

# next line added by reg 09/01/2009 ARRAY /dev/md0 devices=/dev/sdb6,/dev/sdc6 ARRAY /dev/md1 devices=/dev/sdb7,/dev/sdc7
#ARRAY /dev/md2 devices=/dev/sdb8,/dev/sdc8

# definitions of existing MD arrays

# This file was auto-generated on Tue, 08 May 2012 18:26:22 -0700
# by mkconf $Id$ $
```

just quickly started gparted to check if all my dirves show up and fair enough, my partitions 6 & 7 show up just fine on drives sdb and sdc. Also, seems like mdadm is running just fine:

```
$ ps ax | grep mdadm
 1945 ?        Ss     0:00 /sbin/mdadm --monitor --pid-file /run/mdadm/monitor.pid --daemonise --scan --syslog
 7869 pts/8    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto mdadm
$
```

what could be my problem here, I don't quite follow:

```
$ dmesg | tail
[ 1437.716819] EXT4-fs (md0): bad geometry: block count 61034935 exceeds size of device (61034912 blocks)
[ 1437.717197] EXT4-fs (md1): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[ 1437.717422] EXT4-fs (md1): bad geometry: block count 59585077 exceeds size of device (59585056 blocks)
[ 3030.508560] init: nvidia-persistenced main process (21110) terminated with status 1
[ 3757.003367] current rate 16719823 is different from the runtime rate 48000
[ 3757.006356] current rate 10357448 is different from the runtime rate 48000
[ 3850.605129] EXT4-fs (md0): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[ 3850.605299] EXT4-fs (md0): bad geometry: block count 61034935 exceeds size of device (61034912 blocks)
[ 3850.605585] EXT4-fs (md1): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[ 3850.605782] EXT4-fs (md1): bad geometry: block count 59585077 exceeds size of device (59585056 blocks)
reg@regDesktopHome:~/semios$
```

and syslog says nothing but mdadm:

```
$ sudo mdadm --detail --scan
mdadm: cannot open /dev/md/127_0: No such file or directory
ARRAY /dev/md1 metadata=0.90 UUID=0abe503f:401d8d09:cd707cc0:bc3f8165
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=0.90 UUID=91e560f1:4e51d8eb:cd707cc0:bc3f8165
$
```

and mdstat

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid1 sdb6[1] sdc6[0]
      244139648 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid1 sdb7[1] sdc7[0]
      238340224 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md127 : active raid1 sdb3[1] sdc3[0]
      390628416 blocks [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
$
```

and mdadm --detail md0:

```
$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 0.90
  Creation Time : Tue Sep  1 19:15:33 2009
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 244139648 (232.83 GiB 250.00 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 244139648 (232.83 GiB 250.00 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 0
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Sun May  4 21:32:24 2014
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           UUID : 91e560f1:4e51d8eb:cd707cc0:bc3f8165
         Events : 0.75007

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       38        0      active sync   /dev/sdc6
       1       8       22        1      active sync   /dev/sdb6\
```

mdadm --detail md1:

```
reg@regDesktopHome:~/semios$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md1
/dev/md1:
        Version : 0.90
  Creation Time : Tue Sep  8 21:19:15 2009
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 238340224 (227.30 GiB 244.06 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 238340224 (227.30 GiB 244.06 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Sun May  4 21:32:24 2014
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           UUID : 0abe503f:401d8d09:cd707cc0:bc3f8165
         Events : 0.3973383

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       39        0      active sync   /dev/sdc7
       1       8       23        1      active sync   /dev/sdb7
$
```

mdadm --examine sdb6

```
$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdb6
/dev/sdb6:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : 91e560f1:4e51d8eb:cd707cc0:bc3f8165
  Creation Time : Tue Sep  1 19:15:33 2009
     Raid Level : raid1
  Used Dev Size : 244139648 (232.83 GiB 250.00 GB)
     Array Size : 244139648 (232.83 GiB 250.00 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Sun May  4 21:32:24 2014
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : bfa701ff - correct
         Events : 75007


      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     1       8       22        1      active sync   /dev/sdb6

   0     0       8       38        0      active sync   /dev/sdc6
   1     1       8       22        1      active sync   /dev/sdb6
```

mdadm --examine sdb7

```
reg@regDesktopHome:~/semios$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdb7
/dev/sdb7:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : 0abe503f:401d8d09:cd707cc0:bc3f8165
  Creation Time : Tue Sep  8 21:19:15 2009
     Raid Level : raid1
  Used Dev Size : 238340224 (227.30 GiB 244.06 GB)
     Array Size : 238340224 (227.30 GiB 244.06 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 1

    Update Time : Sun May  4 21:32:24 2014
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : 2a7376fd - correct
         Events : 3973383


      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     1       8       23        1      active sync   /dev/sdb7

   0     0       8       39        0      active sync   /dev/sdc7
   1     1       8       23        1      active sync   /dev/sdb7
```

mdadm --examine sdc6

```
reg@regDesktopHome:~/semios$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdc6
/dev/sdc6:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : 91e560f1:4e51d8eb:cd707cc0:bc3f8165
  Creation Time : Tue Sep  1 19:15:33 2009
     Raid Level : raid1
  Used Dev Size : 244139648 (232.83 GiB 250.00 GB)
     Array Size : 244139648 (232.83 GiB 250.00 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Sun May  4 21:32:24 2014
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : bfa7020d - correct
         Events : 75007


      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     0       8       38        0      active sync   /dev/sdc6

   0     0       8       38        0      active sync   /dev/sdc6
   1     1       8       22        1      active sync   /dev/sdb6
```

mdadm --examine sdc7

```
reg@regDesktopHome:~/semios$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdc7
/dev/sdc7:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : 0abe503f:401d8d09:cd707cc0:bc3f8165
  Creation Time : Tue Sep  8 21:19:15 2009
     Raid Level : raid1
  Used Dev Size : 238340224 (227.30 GiB 244.06 GB)
     Array Size : 238340224 (227.30 GiB 244.06 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 1

    Update Time : Sun May  4 21:32:24 2014
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : 2a73770b - correct
         Events : 3973383


      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     0       8       39        0      active sync   /dev/sdc7

   0     0       8       39        0      active sync   /dev/sdc7
   1     1       8       23        1      active sync   /dev/sdb7
$
```

parted says this about sdb:

```
$ sudo parted /dev/sdb unit mib print free
Model: ATA ST31000528AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 953870MiB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start      End        Size       Type      File system     Flags
 1      0.03MiB    95370MiB   95370MiB   primary   ext4            boot
 3      95370MiB   476843MiB  381473MiB  primary   ext4
 2      476843MiB  953859MiB  477016MiB  extended
 6      476843MiB  715261MiB  238418MiB  logical   ext3
 7      715261MiB  948015MiB  232754MiB  logical   ext3
 5      948015MiB  953859MiB  5844MiB    logical   linux-swap(v1)
        953859MiB  953870MiB  10.3MiB              Free Space
```

and this about sdc:

```
reg@regDesktopHome:~/semios$ sudo parted /dev/sdc unit mib print free
Model: ATA ST31000528AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 953870MiB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start      End        Size       Type      File system     Flags
 1      0.03MiB    95370MiB   95370MiB   primary   ext4            boot
 3      95370MiB   476843MiB  381473MiB  primary   ext4
 2      476843MiB  953859MiB  477016MiB  extended
 6      476843MiB  715261MiB  238418MiB  logical   ext3
 7      715261MiB  948015MiB  232754MiB  logical   ext3
 5      948015MiB  953859MiB  5844MiB    logical   linux-swap(v1)
        953859MiB  953870MiB  10.3MiB              Free Space

$
```

So how do I get my array abck up and running? I have some crucial data on these disks and I thought it was safwe with the RAID 1 array...

Comment: Did you ever find out how to resolve the problem?

Comment: Not exactly the best answer, but since I am also experiencing the problem, I filled a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1378850

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gunfus,

Yes, I have resolved the problem. The issue in my particular issue was, that thewe super block of my ext4 partition was corrupted. There's instructions on how to fix it: http://linuxexpresso.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/repair-a-broken-ext4-superblock-in-ubuntu/